# Question about Connectionist Temporal Classification (CTC) gradient

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, speech-recognition

I have read the original [CTC paper by Graves et al](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf), but am confused about equation 16, for which the authors derive the gradient of the negative log likelihood objective with respect to the inputs of the final softmax layer:

$\frac{\partial O^{ML}({(\textbf{x}, \textbf{z})}, \mathcal{N}_w)}{\partial u^t_k} = y^t_k - \frac{1}{y^t_k Z_t} \sum_{s \in lab(\textbf{z}, k)} \hat{\alpha}_t(s)\hat{\beta}_t(s)$

where

$Z_t = \sum_{s = 1}^{|\textbf{l}'|} \frac{\hat{\alpha}_t(s)\hat{\beta}_t(s)}{y^t_{\textbf{l}_{s}'}}$

I can almost derive this expression using the chain rule combined with the fact that the derivative of the softmax is

$S_i(\delta_{ij} - S_j)$.

In particular, my calculations successfully derive the second term in the above expression for the gradient of the objective, but I cannot see how the first term, $y^t_k$, falls out of the calculation. Any help in this derivation would be appreciated.